# Payment Adaptive payments, implicit payment fee

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I want to know if there is any fee to make Implicit payment using adaptive payments to other paypal accounts in the same country.

User can buy product from my app using Credit Card through a third party gateway or paypal.

2nd part of my application will distribute commission to multiple merchants who also have paypal account of the same country.

From what I understand its free to send money from senders paypal account in this case the api owner to another registered paypal account of the same country.

Is my assumption correct ?

Hussain

Answer (score 3):

There is a parameter in the Pay request called feespayer that you can set to specify who pays the fee on a payment.  Possible values are SENDER, PRIMARYRECEIVER, EACHRECEIVER, and SECONDARY ONLY.

See the [Pay API reference](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) for more details.

Comment: Hi Andrew ... I do know about the parameter .. What I want to make sure is whether transfer is free is if it is to multiple receivers having registered PayPal account of the same country ?

Comment: If you set it up as a "personal" payment and the payment is made with cash (paypal or bank funds) then it would be free.  Otherwise a fee will be charged to somebody, which would fall to the feespayer parameter.

Comment: I would use a business account, if there is a charge where can I find details of how much it can be ?

Comment: @AndrewAngell, can you clarify what you mean by "personal" payment?

Comment: When you go through the Send Money tab on PayPal you can choose whether the payment is for goods or services, or if it's to friends and family.  The friends and family used to just be called personal.  If you send money that way there is no fee, again, as long as cash was used to pay.  The Pay API gives you the ability to send personal payments that act the same way,